# Can anybody tell me how to play a sound file in a webpage using javascript or html or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anybody tell me how to play a sound 
file in a webpage using javascript or
 html or jquery?

Comment: Use the search functionality before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 has an [`audio`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) tag, which would make it very easy. Of course, this requires a browser, supporting HTML5.

Comment: can u provide an example but use jquery or javascript ......thanks